# React native Error: The HTTP/S server is already being used by another WebSocket server

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native

I'm trying to run yarn start, not working for me. I have tried changing port but it gives the same result.

```text
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                              │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8084.                                         │
│                                                                              │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to        │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.               │
│                                                                              │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                    │
│                                                                              │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

warning: the transform cache was reset.
master/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:83
        throw new Error(
        ^

Error: The HTTP/S server is already being used by another WebSocket server
    at new WebSocketServer (/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:83:15)
    at InspectorProxy._addDeviceConnectionHandler (/node_modules/metro-inspector-proxy/src/InspectorProxy.js:220:17)
    at InspectorProxy.addWebSocketListener (/node_modules/metro-inspector-proxy/src/InspectorProxy.js:175:10)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/node_modules/metro/src/index.js:265:28)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:509:28)
    at Server.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at emitListeningNT (node:net:1368:10)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:82:21)
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi guy.
It looks like your socket 8084 port has a previous running process. 1. You can enable another port to start
2.You can stop the process to start again.
`lsof -i :8084 -t
kill....`

Comment: I have tried sudo lsof not working with mac Bigsur unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

This may happen for a few reasons:

1. You have run the app using `react-native run-android` or directly from Android Studio (or XCode). When running this command, if the Metro bundler server is not active, it will start it. Doing so, it open the default `Terminal.app` on Mac and appear in your recent app if not pinned. So if you run manually afterward `yarn start` the port will already be used.
2. You are trying to start a second Metro bundler on the same port.

### Recommanded solution

Find the already running server on this port using

```
sudo lsof -i :8084
```

Kill it

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

### Alternative

Change the Metro port.

```
react-native start --port 8088
```

You'll need to access the developer menu on each app re-install to change the bundler location: `localhost:8088` for example.

Comment: I have tried this, unfortunately it doesn't work for me.

Comment: did you try to restart the computer?
If so, are you sure there is not already another bundler started? No terminal/iterm app opening when running yarn start?

Comment: I have tried every possible solution listed on internet, none of them worked for me.

Comment: let's chat here maybe https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242005/react-native-port-already-user